# How to animate a ui view repeatedly with IBAnimatable library

Tags: swift, animation, storyboard

I am using [IBAnimatible](https://github.com/IBAnimatable/IBAnimatable) library to animate a simple UIView using storyboard

When I run the app, the animation (Flash) runs only 2 times and then stops.

How to animate (forever) or repeated 100 times for example.

I cannot find any repeat field

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the `Animatable` protocol has a property called `repeatCount`, which is "[used to specify the count to repeat the animation.](https://github.com/IBAnimatable/IBAnimatable/blob/master/Documentation/APIs.md)". Why not create a custom `UIView` that conforms to `Animatable` and set `repeatCount` to `Float.infinity`? `repeatCount` is compatible with the `flash` animation. If you provide some more context as to what you are wanting to animate, I could provide some code as to how you could do this.

Comment: Thanks. it worked after I created a custom UIView extending Animatable...